# How to redirect homepage for '/{anything}' this path but redirect to profile.blader.php for '/profile/{anything } this path?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2

I can redirect to home.blade.php for anything after '/'  this path. But i need to redirect profile.blade.php file for  '/profile/{anything} this path. how can i solve this ?

I have used  bellows code for redirection to home.blade.php

```
web.php...
-----------------------------
    Route::get('/{any}', function(){
        return view('home');
    })->where('any', '.*');
```

Comment: Woah woah woah. There should not be route definitions in your views. Ever.

Comment: it is not in views but web.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit due to OPs edited question:**

You could do something like that. Notice the section with {any?} . The question mark means, that the parameter is optional. So a call to /profile will also return the profile view file. If this behaviour is not intended you should remove the questionmark and only write {any}.

```
Route::get('/profile/{any?}', function (){
    return view('profile');
})->where('any', '.*');;

Route::get('/{any}', function (){
    return view('home');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

**Old Answer:**

You could simply define that route previously.

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
    return view('test');
});

Route::get('/{any}', function(){
    return view('home');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Comment: please check my question again. I have modified my question.

Comment: This should work in the web.php file. I just tested it with Laravel 5.8

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize you are in fact asking  a 'different' question. I have updated my answer.

Comment: i got my answer. please tell me in ('any', '.*')  why '.*' is used ?  may be * (asterisk) means all but why .(dot) is used ?

Comment: can't we define this route from only one ? instead of defining both separately ?

Comment: '.*' is used because in a regular expression  The . (dot) character means 'every char'. This asterisk means  zero ore more times.

Comment: You cannot do the route constraints you need in just one route definition using the ->where(key, regex) approach. If you want to define only one route in your web.php file you have to use php regex functions to determine which view should be loaded depending on the {any} Parameter.

Comment: reqular expression cheat sheet https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html